# Virtual energy level in the Bloch sphere representation

Tags: quantum-optics, non-linear-optics, bloch-sphere

How the Bloch vector would evolve, if the electron makes a transition to a virtual energy level (placed below the excited state of our two-level atom), as it does in all sorts of phenomena in nonlinear optics?